# Exercise about Flight Connections

Tags: graph-theory

we consider the $10$ airports $A,B...,J$. In the following table a cross indicates that there are air connections between the airports.
[image]

$1)$ Can we go from any city to any other city?
$2)$  How many planes at least must be taken to go from $A$ to $F$ ?

I want just a hints.
For the first question we  can show there exists a Eulerian cycle in the Graphe ?
For the second question we use Dijkstra algorithm?
what do you think ?

Comment: For an Eulerian cycle, obviously not ! (what is necessary condition to have an Eulerian cycle ?).

Comment: @Surb there is no an odd degree

Comment: Yes, and this should answer your question.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title. The word "airport" is mathematically irrelevant.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): what do *you* think?, and focus on one question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest conceptually is to draw the graph and ask if it is connected.  It should be easy to see if it is or not.

If you don't want to use your own pen and paper, you could use an online tool like http://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor

Since you prefer hints, I will link to the image of the graph after I entered the values rather than display the image directly here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkC7b.png

The image reveals a great deal of information about the graph, much of it can be intuitively seen and requires little to no formal proof.

---

If you prefer a more formal proof, construct a **walk** that visits each vertex.  Note, we do not require this to be a path.  We allow vertices and edges to repeat.

Another option, take your matrix... replace the "x"'s with 1's and empty spaces with zeroes.  Calculate the first few powers of the matrix, and add these powers together and see if all entries become nonzero.  (*In larger problems, potentially many powers would need to be calculated... unnecessary here*).

This is also able to answer the question of the quickest path from one vertex to another, though this is admittedly incredibly tedious.